# SOAP - Works locally, works with http://www.soapclient.com/soaptest.html - doesnt work with my client.php

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl

I have a simple SOAP-Setup with a WSDL, a server.php and a client.php. The server only has one function, which adds two numbers.

- Everything works as intendent locally
- Everything works as Intendent, when I test it via "http://www.soapclient.com/soaptest.html"

But it doesnt work with my client.php, which is the same as the working local one.

client.php:

```
$client = new SoapClient("math.wsdl");

var_dump($client->__getFunctions());

$result = $client->__soapCall("add",array(7,2));
//$result = $client->add(20,5);

var_dump($result);
```

I tried both calls (__soapCall & the simple one), but to no awail. It dumps the function of the server thought:

```
array(1) { [0]=> string(23) "int add(int $a, int $b)" }
```

but stops after that, making it the only output.

Bouth the local server and the external server have the same SOAP settings...

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try to put exactly the same WSDL address for your object as you had put into that soaptest site? Instead of just "math.wsdl" i mean.

Comment: If I do that, I get the 500 Server Error. Also it appears that the Client finds the WSDL als the __getFunctions works as it should ...

Comment: More Information: When I put the links to my Online-WSDL & server.php into my local WSDL it still works. So apparently it has something to do with the client.php

Comment: Even more info: When I comment out the first var_dump (the one which returns all functions) and just leave the actual function call, it returns a 500 Server Error...

Comment: When I switch the array parameter in the function call to a string, I get a NULL return value. For example: __soapCall("add","7,2");

Comment: Well - looks like I have the "DND not supported" error, dispite being able to load the WSDL correctly undless I try to request a function. Here is the client: http://extern.fkc-online.de/rh_tests/soap/client.php The webserver runs on port 80, so I can rule out the SOAP-Port Bug ...